# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate causing an unwanted Metadata call

Tags: sql-server, performance, metadata

We noticed that performance wasn't stellar but didn't bother us that much because it was a background process then we were contacted by our DBA who informed us that each stored procedure call was spanning a second call to get metadata from the DB.

Obviously nowhere in our code do we make any such calls and no, we're not using any ORM framework that might be issuing them behind the scenes.

Here's our setup:
- Standalone (no container) Java application
- spring-jdbc-3.2.2 is being used for data access
- we're using Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server
- we're using this syntax: CALL SPROC_NAME(:PAR_1)

Any pointers on how remove this extra call are really appreciated. I haven't been able to turn on logging for the SQL Server driver so my next step is to try to debug the spring JDBC code.

Thanks,
MV

Answer (score 1):

Like I said, every Stored Procedure invocation (using PreparedStatement) was causing 2 calls to the DB with the first call being really expensive: 
exec sp_sproc_columns @procedure_name =SPROC_NAME,  @ODBCVer=3 (metadata call)
EXEC SPROC_NAME @P0, @P1, @P2, @P3 (actual call)

After reading the following thread we finally had something to work with:
[Why is calling a stored procedure always preceded by a call to sp_sproc_columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442364/why-is-calling-a-stored-procedure-always-preceded-by-a-call-to-sp-sproc-columns)

Even though we're using JDBC instead of ADO.NET the issue seemed very similar to ours therefore we decided it was worth giving it a try.

After the change was in place a trace session in the DB confirmed the first call to be no longer present in the logs.

Previously we were passing a Map as parameters. The moment we switched to Map and specified the proper data type we started seeing performance improvements.

In short, if the driver has all the data (actually metadata) about the params then it doesn't issue the metadata call.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since this question was posted; However, I'll leave my answer given that I was having this issue at work and it took me quite a while to figure out. Hope it helps somebody.

**Short Answer:** Do not use named parameters in your procedure calls. Use ordered parameters instead.

**Long Answer:** When using named parameters, the JDBC driver issues a call to the 'sp_sproc_columns' procedure first. The driver issues this call in order to get the name of the parameters in the procedure and runs some validations in order to check if the names are correct. It later replaces the named parameters in your query and puts them in the correct order. Once the correct order is determined, the driver issues the call to the procedure using ordered parameters instead.

View the call in the source code. https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerCallableStatement.java#L1254